# How to get the current/this object on button click using bind event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
$(document).bind('click', '.btn-yes .btn-no', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");
    alert("test"); // <-- this works...
});
```

`.btn-yes` and `.btn-no` are two classes which are attached to buttons. When they are clicked, I want the `btn-warning` class to get attached to that button, but this is not working...

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind('click','.btn-yes .btn-no',function(e){
        $(e.target).toggleClass("btn-warning");
});
```

Comment: `e` is the `event` object, not the one you think. Probably you want to use `e.target`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was the correct one. I added event and it worked correctly.

Comment: This solution attaches the btn-warning class to ANY DOM element that was clicked on, and not just to the buttons..

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a comma `,` between your selector:

```
'.btn-yes, .btn-no'
```

and you should use event delegation only if your elements are dynamically generated after page load.

If such a case then the preferred method is `.on()` as per latest jQuery library. You can see this in action in the snippet below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-yes, .btn-no', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-warning');
});
```

```css
.btn-warning{background:red; color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn-yes'>Yes</button><button class='btn-no'>No</button>
```

---

### Problem:

When you don't use comma `,` in your selector such as in this case you are actually trying to bind a click event on the child `.btn-no` which has the parent `.btn-yes`.

Comment: I used comma, but I still have the same problem

Comment: or, if *both* classes need to apply, remove the space: `'.btn-yes.btn-no'`

Comment: `'.btn-yes.btn-no'` will look for element which is having both classes. @T3H40

Comment: That's what I said, isn't it?

Comment: @Marc for working example one should post the markup of its own as OP hasn't provided, then that would be based on assumptions. although i would add it.

Comment: Feel free to take the JSFiddle from my answer below and try your code

Comment: @Marc i got your point. better to bind the event with `.on()` in case of event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

`'.btn-yes .btn-no'` denotes to the btn-no inside btn-yes not separate elements. So, separate your elements with a comma and use click event for that.

I also recommend you to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of bind method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-yes, .btn-no', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery version 1.7+ use `on` method

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-yes,.btn-no', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");

});
```